# Нажатие кнопок на сайте с помощью webbrowser

Tags: c#, winforms

Есть своё приложение, в котором я с помощью webbrowser'а захожу на сайт, там я хочу, нажав кнопочку из приложения, нажать 2 кнопочки на сайте. Т.е. сначала жму одну кнопку, прогружается страница, а там 2-я нужная мне кнопка.

Проблема в том, что после того, как нажимаю 1-ю кнопоку, вторая не жмется, но если я заново нажму кнопку из приложения, тогда 2-я кнопка жмется. По всей видимости не успевает отрисоваться страничка перед тем, как будет нажата 2-я кнопка. Как сделать так, чтобы 2-я кнопка нажималась только тогда, когда будет полностью прогружена страница?

Вот код:

```
private void button3_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    HtmlWindow frames = webBrowser1.Document.Window.Frames[0];            
    var elements1 = frames.Document.GetElementsByTagName("input");
    foreach (HtmlElement element in elements1)
    {
        string attrValue = element.GetAttribute("value");
        if (attrValue == "Кнопка1")
        {
            element.InvokeMember("click");
            break;
        }
    }
    //ищем 2ю кнопку и пробуем нажать
    frames = webBrowser1.Document.Window.Frames[0];
    var elements = frames.Document.GetElementsByTagName("img");
    foreach (HtmlElement element in elements)
    {
        string attrValue = element.GetAttribute("alt");
        if (attrValue == "Кнопка2")
        {
            element.InvokeMember("click");
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Пробовал ставить задержки, между нажатием 1ой и 2ой кнопки, но тогда приложение себя странно ведет, сначала отрабатывает задержка, а потом только нажимается 1я кнопка.

Comment: В вашем случае нужно дождаться, пока загрузится новая страница после нажатия первой кнопки. Для этого нужно обработать событие `DocumentCompleted`. Грубо говоря, код нажатия второй кнопки должен быть в этом событии.

Comment: Да, сработало )

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov разместите ваш комментарий как ответ, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В вашем случае нужно дождаться, пока загрузится новая страница после нажатия первой кнопки. Для этого нужно обработать событие `DocumentCompleted`. Грубо говоря, код нажатия второй кнопки должен быть в этом событии.